# Mantra Lekhan (Writing) and its relevance in Vaishnavism

Tags: krishna, ramayana, mantras, vaishnavism, yoga

What is Mantra Lekhan or Mantra Writing? Please provide references from the scriptures for this practice.

Answer (score 1):

Mantra Lekhan is an ancient Vedic science which involves deeply visualization of the syllables of a Mantra within the mind and has been practiced since thousands of years.

Below link contains bountiful research done by [Srila Bhaktiratna Sadhu Maharaj](https://lekhan.org/) to present references of Mantra Writing in the Vaishnava scriptures.

https://raadhaa.com/d/24-30-scriptural-proof-of-namlekhan
https://lekhan.org/photos/
https://lekhan.org/

Below is a preview of the collection of photos from the above links:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: "#5...Vaishnava tantra, Valmiki Ramayana" - where in Valmiki Ramayana is this found?

Comment: japaat SHATA gunam punyam ।
ram-nam PRALEKHANE ।।

Comment: Would appreciate any help in finding the shloka number.

Comment: Please read [Guidelines for new users answering questions](http://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125). Since it's your answer the onus is on you to back it up with credible sources.

Comment: I searched for 'japa' [here](http://www.sanskrit-linguistics.org/dcs/index.php?contents=dictionary&limit=20&first_letter=j&page=29) but didn't find any references in Valmiki Ramayana (VR) so must be some other text. Also, Rama did not become a god until many centuries later so it'd be strange to find a reference to 'rama nama japa' in VR.